# Calling one async function inside another in redux-thunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux-thunk

I'm building a react app and use redux-thunk for async operations. I have two functions `getActivities()` and `createActivity()` and I want to call the former after successful calling the latter. But if I put `getActivities()` inside `then` block of `createActivity()` it simply isn't get called (which is proved by not seeing console.log() which I put in `getActivities()`). Here are both functions:

```
export const getActivities = () => dispatch => {
console.log('again');
return axios.get(ENV.stravaAPI.athleteActivitiesBaseEndPoint, autHeaders)
    .then(resp => {
        dispatch({type: actions.GET_ACTIVITIES, activities: resp.data})
    })
    .catch(err => {
        if(window.DEBUG)console.log(err);
    })
};

export const createActivity = data => dispatch => {

dispatch(setLoadingElement('activityForm'));
return axios.post(URL, null, autHeaders)
    .then(resp => {
        if (resp.status === 201) {
            dispatch(emptyModal());
        }
        // I WANT TO CALL getActivities() HERE
        dispatch(unsetLoadingElement('activityForm'));
    })
    .catch(err => {
        if(window.DEBUG) console.log(err.response.data.errors);
        dispatch(unsetLoadingElement('activityForm'));
    });
};
```

How can I call one inside another?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to call another action from inside one action creator you just need to just `dispatch` the action like `dispatch(getActivities())`

```
export const createActivity = data => dispatch => {

    dispatch(setLoadingElement('activityForm'));
    return axios.post(URL, null, autHeaders)
        .then(resp => {
            if (resp.status === 201) {
                dispatch(emptyModal());
            }
            dispatch(getActivities());
            dispatch(unsetLoadingElement('activityForm'));
        })
        .catch(err => {
            if(window.DEBUG) console.log(err.response.data.errors);
            dispatch(unsetLoadingElement('activityForm'));
        });
 };
```

Comment: that really works!! I was completely assured that we can dispatch only action creators, which return action objects, but was unaware about dispatching other async functions. Thanks a lot, you saved me a lot of time)

Comment: Not a problem, the concept remains the same whether or not its a `thunk` or not, the only difference is in the initial configuration, Glad it helped you

Answer (score 0):

```
getActivites()
```

This **does** sucessfully call `getActivities()`. However, it returns an anonymous function which contains the `console.log()` call. You ignore this returned value here.

You must dispatch the returned function in order to ensure it is called:

```
dispatch(getActivities())
```