# Execute thunk function inside another thunk function in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

How can I execute a thunk function inside another thunk function? Using `dispatch()`, as in JavaScript, I get this error, because I suppose that the `dispatch` method expects an action creator, not a thunk function:

[image]

`logoutTimeout` is a thunk function (async function that dispatches an actionCreator, while `authSuccess` is a simple actionCreator. The picture above is a screenshot of the code inside a thunk function. My question is how can I dispatch the thunk function `logoutTimeout`(could be any) inside this thunk function I took a pic of (in **typescript**)?

[HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-frog-mz94l?file=/src/Store/Actions.ts) is a codesandbox sample.

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of screenshot

Comment: @slideshowp2 I think the question is simple enough that it wouldn't need one. It's only about what would be the proper way to ```dispatch thunk functions inside other thunk functions```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling one async function inside another in redux-thunk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48359313/calling-one-async-function-inside-another-in-redux-thunk)

Comment: @captain-yossarian thank you, but no. That's how you would do it in JS, not TS. TS function ```dispatch``` expects type ```AnyAction```, as seen in my picture

Comment: it would be easier to answer if you share your reproducible example, otherwise I can only  guess

Comment: Try to put `as AnyAction` after `logoutTimeout(tokenExpiresIn)`.

Comment: Added a codesandbox sample